# Octave mod function

Tags: math, octave, modulo

How can I write this equation in Octave?

C = (X ∗ 2 + 4) mod 26

I tried to use the function `mod()` in this way

```
c = mod(26,(X * 2 + 4))
```

but it returned all values as 26.

Comment: You got the parameters the wrong way round.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't under stand
can you write it for me PLZ

Comment: Read the documentation: https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/mod.html (or just type `help mod` in Octave).

Comment: `c = mod((X * 2 + 4), 26)`